# Chart.js get array of currently visible points on graph

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js, export-to-csv

Using Chart.js with zoom/pan enabled, I am trying to write a function to export only what is visible on the canvas to CSV.

But I cannot figure out how to get only the visible datapoints after the user zooms/pans.

I know I can just look at `myChart.data.datasets` but that would fetch all the points in the chart, not just the currently visible ones.

```
var config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        // data is from API call
    }
        pan: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'xy'
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'xy'
        },
        bezierCurve : false
    }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);

$('#exportTheseRunsToCSV').on('click', function() {
    // something like myChart.getVisibleDataPoints() ???
    console.log(chart)
    console.log(chart.data.datasets)
});
```

There has to be some internal API call to get the visible points, as I also have a function to export the current visible points to PNG and that only grabs what is currently drawn on the canvas:

```
<a id="exportTheseRuns" class="text-white" href="#" download="image.png" download><i class="fas fa-download"></i> Export to PNG</a>

$('#exportTheseRuns').on('click', function() {
    $('#exportTheseRuns').attr('href', myChart.toBase64Image());
})
```

The function `.toBase64Image()` seems like it internally does what I am looking for, as it will only capture visible points, but then it returns a Base64 URI which I can't use for my `arrayToCSV` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chart object contains `minIndex` and `maxIndex` properties that can be used to [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the dataset for the visible values.

Here's a snippet showing how to use the [plugin-provided functions `onPanComplete` and `onZoomComplete`](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom#configuration) to output the visible values after panning or zooming the chart:

```js
function getVisibleValues({
  chart
}) {
  let x = chart.scales["x-axis-0"];

  document.getElementById("vv").innerText = JSON.stringify(chart.data.datasets[0].data.slice(x.minIndex, x.maxIndex + 1));
}

new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 'c',
          max: 'h'
        }
      }]
    },
    plugins: {
      zoom: {
        pan: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: 'x',
          onPanComplete: getVisibleValues
        },
        zoom: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: 'x',
          onZoomComplete: getVisibleValues
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.1"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-zoom@0.7.4"></script>
<canvas id="chart" style="max-height:125px"></canvas>
<p>
  Visible values: <span id="vv"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is precisely what I was looking for. I thought there'd be a baked in function, but this works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `toBase64Image` function does not what you want, it just gets the data URL from the canvas.

[toBase64Image on github.com/chartjs](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/50fd869334b389046986e8f69fa4741ff087fad4/src/core/core.controller.js#L923)

```
toBase64Image: function() {
  return this.canvas.toDataURL.apply(this.canvas, arguments);
},
```

You can get the updated chart data with `onZoomComplete` and `onPanComplete`, they both get an object that contains `chart` from this you might get more information about the current zoom, but as far as I can see you will need to do some calculations/work to get the visible points...