# react-chartjs-2 get visible values after pan/zoom with chartjs-plugin-zoom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

Is there any way to get the visible values on a chart after zooming or panning, using react-chartjs-2? I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609850/chart-js-get-array-of-currently-visible-points-on-graph) without the react version, but I'm not sure how to reference the "chart object" in react. I tried the solution as is, but it doesn't display the visible values, but rather keeps increasing the height of my charts (stretches downwards).

So what would the react solution look like?

Here's my attempt with the linked solution

options:

```
const chartStyle = {
  options: {
    animation: false,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      zoom: {
        zoom: {
          wheel: {
            enabled: true,
            modifierKey: "shift",
          },
          pinch: {
            enabled: true,
          },
          enabled: true,
          drag: true,
          mode: "x",
          onZoomComplete: getVisibleValues,
        },
        pan: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: "x",
          speed: 2,
          onPanComplete: getVisibleValues,
        },
        mode: "xy",
      },
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
    },

    scales: {
      y: {
        type: "linear",
        display: "true",
        position: "left",
        grid: {
          drawBorder: true,
          color: "#000000",
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          color: "#000000",
        },
      },

      x: {
        max: 9,
        grid: {
          drawBorder: true,
          color: "#00000",
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: false,
          color: "#000000",
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

function getVisibleValues({ chart }) {
  let x = chart.scales["x-axis-0"];

  document.getElementById("vv").innerText = JSON.stringify(
    chart.data.datasets[0].data.slice(x.minIndex, x.maxIndex + 1)
  );
}
export default chartStyle;
```

Here's my attempt at accessing the chart instance with useRef(), but ref.scales is undefined:

```
const SingleChart = ({ chosenDevice, variable }) => {
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: variable,
        data: [],
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: "rgb(0,0,0)",
        borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0, 0.8)",
        color: "rgb(0,0,0)",
        pointRadius: 4,
        yAxisID: "y",
      },
    ],
  });

  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState({});
  const processEnv = process.env;

  // USEREF ATTEMPT
  const ref = useRef();
  console.log(ref.scales);
  let x = ref.scales["x"];
  console.log("min index", x.minIndex);
  console.log("max index", x.maxIndex);

  useEffect(() => {
    ChartComp.register(zoomPlugin);
    var chartDataUrl = processEnv.REACT_APP_CHART_API + chosenDevice;
    async function updatePPK() {
      if (chosenDevice !== "") {
        const dataResponse = await fetch(chartDataUrl);
        var dataBody = await dataResponse.json();
        for (var key in dataBody) {
          dataBody[key].PV_POWER =
            dataBody[key].PV_CURR * dataBody[key].PV_CURR;
        }
        setApiData(dataBody);
      }
    }

    updatePPK();
  }, [chosenDevice]);

  useEffect(() => {
    var chartLabels = [];
    var chartValues = [];
    console.log(apiData);
    console.log("keys", Object.keys(apiData) !== 0);
    if (Object.keys(apiData).length !== 0) {
      for (var key in apiData) {
        if (variable == "GEN_ON") {
          chartValues.push(apiData[key][variable] == "ON" ? 1 : 0);
        } else {
          chartValues.push(apiData[key][variable]); // for every element in the passed in chartData object from hookMqtt, add the variable the graph requests (this.variable) to an array of data to be displayed
        }
        chartLabels.push(apiData[key]["TIME_COMMITED"].substring(11, 19));
      }
      setChartData({
        labels: chartLabels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: variable,
            data: chartValues,
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: "rgb(0,0,0)",
            borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0, 0.8)",
            color: "rgb(0,0,0)",
            pointRadius: 4,
            yAxisID: "y",
          },
        ],
      });
      console.log(chartData);
    }
  }, [chosenDevice, apiData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Line
        ref={ref}
        data={chartData}
        options={variable != "GEN_ON" ? chartStyles.options : genStyle.options}
        width={20}
        height={10}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

SingleChart.propTypes = {
  chartData: PropTypes.any,
  chosenDevice: PropTypes.any,
  setDate: PropTypes.any,
  variable: PropTypes.any,
  state: PropTypes.any,
};
export default SingleChart;
```

Comment: It should be the same as the chart gets passed to the function as an argument, also you dont show any of the options so people cant see where you went wrong with trying to implement it

Comment: My bad, options added. In the react-chartjs-2 documentation, it says that the chart's instance can be accessed with `const ref = useRef(); return <Doughnut ref={ref} data={data} options={options} />;` . Then I tried getting `ref.scales["x-axis-0"].minIndex` but ref.scales is undefined.

Comment: Nevermind! I found the answer. Looks like in chartjs3 you can access the currently visible ticks with chart.scales.x.ticks; The solution I linked works